# Flutter Error when I'm trying to connect firebase into Flutter

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
> Searched Location:
> C:\Users\Anubhav7\Desktop\Projects\Netflix Clone\netflix_clone\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
> C:\Users\Anubhav7\Desktop\Projects\Netflix Clone\netflix_clone\android\app\src\google-services.json
> C:\Users\Anubhav7\Desktop\Projects\Netflix Clone\netflix_clone\android\app\google-services.json

Answer (score 0):

The error says

> File google-services.json is missing

Just make sure your google-services.json file in the right place.

For android; android->app,
For ios; ios->Runner

Comment: I already done that but still arising this issue i don't know how to fix this

Comment: can you tell me how to add this manually

Comment: did you fix it yet?

Comment: no occurring same problem can even after placing the file in right place.....

Comment: plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' when i remove this plugin than no error show but after adding this thisabove error show...